# Positioning h3, img and p

Tags: html, css, css-float

Ok this is probably pretty easy, but I've been fiddling with it four an hour and still couldn't position it the way I wanted.

http://jsfiddle.net/Yx65d/9/

I'm trying to put the h3 on top of the img, both of them floated left, and the p aligned right, like this :

http://s10.postimage.org/gq1lgcm15/example.jpg

Comment: For future reference: only use `clear:both` when you really need it. That is, start with none, and only add it in places where you need to actually clear the float in a particular direction. I think you've stuck a `clear: both` on almost every single CSS selector in your code, which explains why none of your floats actually float.

Comment: Post your image and add your code to the question. Otherwise it will be useless for a future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this solution for your problem: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yx65d/11/) you had too many clear both

Answer (score 1):

Here's the my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Yx65d/10/